# Numpy einsum fails for matrix product with unspecified leading and trailing axes

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to use dot product between the leading and trailing axes of arrays with unspecified dimensions. einsum doesn't seem to accommodate this use case. User error?

With `prnd=np.random.RandomState()`,

```
np.einsum('...i,i...', prnd.rand(5,2), prnd.rand(2,3)) 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_1106807/647899105.py", line 1, in <module>
    np.einsum('...i,i...', prnd.rand(5,2), prnd.rand(2,3))

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in einsum

  File "/home/elliot/anaconda3/envs/current/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py", line 1359, in einsum
    return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (5,2)->(5,2) (2,3)->(3,2)
```

should be the same as...

```
np.einsum('ai,ib', prnd.rand(5,2), prnd.rand(2,3)).shape
Out[69]: (5, 3)

np.__version__
Out[70]: '1.21.4'
```

Comment: That's not how '...' works in `einsum`

Comment: Indices elided with `...` are expected to broadcast together.

Comment: At the risk of being redundant, the error message specifically states that this is a **broadcast together** issue.  Think of it this way, what would it take to broadcast a (5,) shape with a (3,) shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it has nothing to do with `np.random.RandomState()`, it works just the same with e.g. `np.ones`. Note that if you use ellipsis `...` as part of the input shapes, the ellipsis will stand for the *same* (up to the [rules of broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)) shape throughout the whole expression. In your case you try (slightly rewritten)

```
a = np.ones((5, 2))
b = np.ones((2, 3))
np.einsum('...i,i...->...', a, b)
```

But in `a` the ellipsis stands for `5` while in `b` the ellipsis stands for `3` which cannot be broadcast together, that is there is no possible output shape satisfying the broadcasting rules.

What would work is

```
a = np.ones((5, 2))
b = np.ones((2, 5))
```

or

```
a = np.ones((5, 2))
b = np.ones((2, 1))
```

or

```
a = np.ones((5, 2))
b = np.ones((2,))
```

But you can't use ellipsis to "glue together" the trailing or leading dimensions to a new shape.